# Request.ApplicationPath is in not working

Tags: asp.net

My app is structured like this:

```
 MyProject
    -Tracking
      - TrackingPage.aspx
    -master
      -mymaster
```

in the `mymaster` page, I have link like this:

```
 string sApplicationPath = Request.ApplicationPath;

pStr = pStr + "<li id='Home'><a class='top' href='";
        pStr = pStr + sApplicationPath;
        pStr = pStr + "/Tracking/TrackingPage.aspx'>Home</a></li>";
```

When run the app in it works, but when I put that in IIS, it gives me:

```
 http://117.**.**.134/mysit/Tracking/TrackingPage.aspx.
```

when I click the link it navigates me to wrong palce:

```
http://117.**.**.134/mysit/master/Tracking/TrackingPage.aspx.
```

How to can I fix this issue?

Comment: Why are u appending? What issue is causing when writing only `/Tracking/TrackingPage.aspx` ?

Comment: if anyone find you can't use `HttpContext.Current.Request` or `Request.ApplicationPath`, try `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;`

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to get the hostname of the current URL? If so have a look at:

[Request.Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url.aspx)

You can also have a look at the properties of the Uri class, to see what you can extract from the URL, or you can create a new Uri with the old one and a relative path string or Uri.

[Uri class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx)

Eventually I think what you want to do is:

```
Uri url = new Uri(Request.Url, "/Tracking/TrackingPage.aspx");
pStr = pStr + "<li id='Home'><a class='top' href='";
pStr = pStr + url.ToString();
pStr = pStr + "'>Home</a></li>";
```

Comment: @PKKG Why should it be in the comment section? I present a feasible solution to the question at hand in the OP.

Comment: did you try `System.IO.Path.Combine` ?

Comment: @PKKG I know of that method, but why would you use it over the constructor of Uri that combines an absolute Uri with a relative string/Uri? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hst1w91.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ceyeze4f.aspx